# How to get the list of tables that has specific columns from Oracle server.?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2,

I have access to an Oracle server from linked server with read-only access.

Now I want to get the list of tables from the Oracle server which has specific column.

For an example I want all the tables that have "Business address" column.

Please help if you have any idea / tips.!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the privileges and assuming that the actual name of the column is `BUSINESS_ADDRESS`, not a case-sensitive column name that includes a space.

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
  FROM dba_tab_columns
 WHERE column_name = 'BUSINESS_ADDRESS'
```

If not, you can use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` if you only care about tables that the Oracle user you are connecting as can query or `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` if you only care about tables the Oracle user you are connecting as owns.

Comment: But the issue is,..I am using SQL SERVER 2008r2 and In that I have only read-only access to the oracle server which is there in Linked server folder. can I still use your solution?

Comment: @user2040021 - But you said that you have a linked server.  So I'm assuming you know how to run queries against Oracle via that linked server.  Is that a bad assumption?

Comment: I am so sorry , I made a mess. Actually I am using SQL SERVER 2008r2 , in that I have an access of Oracle Server which is there in LINKED SERVER folder of SQL SERVER 2008r2. Now the issue is I need to retrive all the tables from that oracle server that has specific column called "Business_Address".

Comment: @user2040021 - "read-only access" can mean lots of different things.  If you have been given the privileges to read the data dictionary, then you can read from the `dba_tab_columns` table.  If not, then you can only look for those tables that you have access to (or that you own) that also have the column you're interested in.  You wouldn't be able to check every table in the database for the column if you haven't been given privileges to do that.

Comment: WHEN I TRIED TO RUN IT LIKE AS FOLLOWS SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM [10.123.12.12]..ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'L%'; IT GIVE ME FOLLOWING ERROR Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name '[10.123.12.12]..ALL_TAB_COLUMNS'

Answer (score 0):

- It is possible that you do not have access to some views.
- It is possible that you do not have access to any view.

But if you have the access you can run the following SQL statements:

```
/* schema you are connected to */
SELECT  table_name
FROM    user_tab_columns
WHERE   LOWER(column_name) LIKE '%business%address%'
;

/* all schemas you have access to*/
SELECT  owner, table_name
FROM    all_tab_columns
WHERE   LOWER(column_name) LIKE '%business%address%'
;
```

- You can create temporary table and catch results into it.

Comment: WHEN I TRIED TO RUN IT LIKE AS FOLLOWS                         SELECT
      TABLE_NAME,
      COLUMN_NAME
   FROM
      [10.123.12.12]..ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
   WHERE
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'L%';                                                                       IT GIVE ME FOLLOWING ERROR                                       Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name '[10.123.12.12]..ALL_TAB_COLUMNS'.

Comment: SELECT * FROM linked_server_name..oracle_schema.oracle_table;